# insert data into mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, json, database

im a beginner in python language , and im trying to insert my json file data into my database table using python but the problem is i have no errors i just get :

tweet number  49634  is uploading to the server

i don't get where the problem is, please i would appreciate any help

```
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port='3306', user='root', password='nihad147', database='tweets')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql_request='insert ignore into tweet_location (latitude, longitude, tweet_id) values (%s,%s,%s)'""

myJsonFile = open('tweet.json', encoding="utf-8")
c = 0



for line in myJsonFile:
  c = c + 1
print("tweet number ", c, " is uploading to the server")
data = json.loads(line)
#line = line.replace('','')

tweet = "SELECT * FROM tweet WHERE tweet_id = '" + str(data['tweet_id']) + "'"
mycursor.execute(tweet)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

row_count = mycursor.rowcount
if row_count == 0:
 if 'location' in data.keys() and data['location'] != None and 'address' in data['location']:
  latitude = data ['location']['lat']
  longitude=data ['location']['lon']


mycursor.execute(sql_request, (latitude,longitude,data['tweet_id']))
print ('------------')


mydb.commit ()
```

here's an example of my json file data:

```
{"tweet_id":"1261276320878788609",
"date":"Fri May 15 12:44:42 +0000 2020",
"raw_text":"برنامج وطني لدعم المبدعين في مواجهة #كورو"
"geo_source":"user_location",
"location":{"address":
{"country":"Tunisia","country_code":"tn","state_district":"غزالة","county":"العرب","state":"Bizerte"},
"response":
"{'place_id': 235309103, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'relation', 'osm_id': 7124228, 'boundingbox': ['37.105957', '37.2033466', '9.4739053', '9.6124953'], 'lat': '37.1551868', 'lon': '9.54834183807249', 'display_name': 'العرب, غزالة, Bizerte, Tunisia', 'class': 'boundary', 'type': 'administrative', 'importance': 0.45, 'icon': '/data/nominatimimages/mapicons/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png','address':{'county': 'العرب', 'state_district': 'غزالة', 'state': 'Bizerte', 'country': 'Tunisia', 'country_code': 'tn'}}",
"geohash":"snwg37buskzd","query_term":"arab","lon":9.54834183807249,"lat":37.1551868},
"user_friends_count":61,"user_description":"I love UAE and his great leadership",
"user_created_at":"Wed Oct 09 11:41:41 +0000 2013",
"user_screen_name":"SikandarMirani",
"user_id_str":"706377881",
"user_verified":false,
"user_statuses_count":50804,
"user_followers_count":946,
"user_location":"Dubai United Arab Emirates"}
```

and this my table's attributes tweet:
tweet_id,
id_user,
text,
tweet_location,
created_at,
name_screen,
categorie_id,

Comment: Please use proper 4-space indents, it's really hard to read the code with just 1 space.

Comment: Why are you only getting `location` from the JSON when the tweet ID isn't found in the `tweet` table.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the JSON file one line at a time. Use `json.load()` to load the entire file into a dictionary.

Use a parameter in the query that selects the tweet, rather that concatenating `data['tweet_id']` into the SQL.

The code that inserts the new row should be inside all the `if` statements that set `latitude` and `longitude` from the data. In fact, you might as well put all the database code inside the `if` statement that checks whether `location` is set in the `JSON`.

```
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port='3306', user='root', password='nihad147', database='tweets')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql_request='insert ignore into tweet_location (latitude, longitude, tweet_id) values (%s,%s,%s)'""

with open('tweet.json', encoding="utf-8") as myJsonFile:
    data = json.load(myJsonFile)

if data.get('location') and 'address' in data['location']:
    tweet = "SELECT 1 FROM tweet WHERE tweet_id = %s"
    mycursor.execute(tweet, (data['tweet_id'],))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    row_count = len(myresult)
    if row_count == 0:
        print(f"Inserting {data['tweet_id']} to the database");
        latitude = data['location']['lat']
        longitude = data['location']['lon']
        mycursor.execute(sql_request, (latitude,longitude,data['tweet_id']))
        mydb.commit ()
        print ('------------')
    else:
        print(f"Tweet {data['tweet_id']} is already in the database")
```